# Can the min/max value of a quotient be calculated for a simple division?

Tags: divisibility

If I have a simple division $x \over y$ I can rewrite it as $x = Qy +R$, (where Q is the Quotient and R is the remainder).

I know that $|y| > R \ge 0$.

Is there a similar rule for the quotient?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is always true that $|x| > |Q| \geq 0$.

Comment: I guess this makes sense, and if |x| > |y| then could we say |x - y|>|Q|≥ |y|?

Comment: @SimonGoodman I don't think so. Take $x=25$ and $y=24$ for example, then that fails.